# How to resolve SElinux denials in android 12 for tcontext with _app extension e.g. tcontext=priv_app

Tags: selinux, android-12, toolbox

I am getting denials even after adding allow rules in the corresponding .te file. Below error I am getting for toolbox. I have added "allow toolbox platform_app:file read;" in toolbox.te file. But still these errors are  not getting resolved. All the tcontext have _app type and they are also associated with some number e.g. c512, c768. Has anybody faced these type of error? How I should fix these.

07-27 04:54:52.613  2490  2490 W killall : type=1400 audit(0.0:2293): avc: denied { read } for scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.613  2490  2490 I auditd  : type=1400 audit(0.0:2294): avc: denied { read } for comm="killall" scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:secure_element:s0:c44,c260,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.613  2490  2490 W killall : type=1400 audit(0.0:2294): avc: denied { read } for scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:secure_element:s0:c44,c260,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.613  2490  2490 I auditd  : type=1400 audit(0.0:2295): avc: denied { read } for comm="killall" scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.613  2490  2490 W killall : type=1400 audit(0.0:2295): avc: denied { read } for scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.616  2490  2490 I auditd  : type=1400 audit(0.0:2296): avc: denied { read } for comm="killall" scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.616  2490  2490 W killall : type=1400 audit(0.0:2296): avc: denied { read } for scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.616  2490  2490 I auditd  : type=1400 audit(0.0:2297): avc: denied { read } for comm="killall" scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c86,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

07-27 04:54:52.616  2490  2490 W killall : type=1400 audit(0.0:2297): avc: denied { read } for scontext=u:r:toolbox:s0 tcontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c86,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0